# Add selectedValue from selectonemenu to list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, arraylist, managed-bean, selectonemenu

So, here's the deal:
I have a selectOneMenu in my view:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.person.personStates.state}" id="estadoRg"
    converter="entityConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{stateBean.states}" var="state" 
        itemLabel=#{state.name}" itemValue="#{state}">
    </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Where personStates is a list containing person, state n date.
Is it possible to add the value from the itemValue directly to the personStates list? (I have a addPersonState method autobuilt in my PersonModel)

If not, how should I do this?
I don't want to add one state instance for each selectOneMenu (will be 5) in my personBean...
Was it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle it via `selectedState` value and then you can bind it for specific person:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{stateBean.selectedState}" id="estadoRg"
    converter="entityConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{stateBean.states}" var="state" 
        itemLabel=#{state.name}" itemValue="#{state}">
    </f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This is the way how `p:selectOneMenu` is used, to be able to bind selected state and the person call a method:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{personBean.matchStates}" />
```

And backing bean method:

```
public void matchStates {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ElContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    Object stateBean = elContext.getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "stateBean"). 
    State selectedState = stateBean.getSelectedState();
    personList.get(index).setState = selectedState;
}
```

Comment: Ok... that cleared my mind... only thing i'm changing is that the method will be handled by ajax.... thnx very much